# Bug : 'mesh', 'off' doesn't work in pdeplot with 'countour' 'on'

Tags: matlab, mesh, contour, figure, pde

I have a problem with the command pdeplot, precisely with 'mesh', 'off'. Example 1 works very well, I mean that the mesh is not represented when I plot my data.

exemple 1 :

`pdeplot(points, seg, tri, 'xydata', P1(:,1), 'mesh', 'off', 'colormap', 'jet');`

Whereas example 2 with the contour option, the mesh off no longer works. it plots contours but also the mesh.

example 2 :

```
pdeplot(points, seg, tri, 'xydata', P1(:,1), 'mesh', 'off', 'contour', 'on', 'levels', 50, 'colormap', 'jet');
```

I would be grateful to who can help me with that.

Comment: Try setting the `mesh` to `off` after creation: `h = pdeplot(); set(h, 'mesh', 'off')`. Maybe the order of inputs matters here. Try putting `mesh` parameter last in your constructor.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time.
I have already tried to change the place of `mesh`,`off` and always the same problem. 
When I try your suggestion with `set(h, 'mesh', 'off')`, I get this error message `Error using matlab.graphics.primitive.world.Group/set
There is no mesh property on the Patch class.`

I found a way to solve this bug. Select edit plot and clic on the plot (mesh) then in the Property Editor - Line, you choose 'none' for the line and Marker.

But, if you have an other idea to do it with a line command i am interested.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't realize it was a patch (because I don't have the right toolboxes to test this directly). To fix it from the command line call `set(h, 'EdgeColor', 'none', 'LineStyle', 'none')`

Comment: I've added it as a formal answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely seems like a bug that could be reported to the Mathworks, but in the meantime you can take the `patch` object that is returned by your call to `pdeplot` and set the `EdgeColor` to `none` and the `LineStyle` to `none` to prevent the grid from showing.

```
h = pdeplot(points, seg, tri, 'xydata', P1(:,1), 'mesh', 'off', 'contour', 'on', 'levels', 50, 'colormap', 'jet');

set(h, 'LineStyle', 'none', 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```